# Indexing collection of objects for O(log(n)) removal or better

Tags: javascript, collections, lookup-tables

I want to store a collection of javascript objects.

Each object represents a time, and a set of properties relating to that time. For example, this could be a scheduled task - a time at which a task is to be executed.

My question is what data structure and algorithm is a good choice for `Scheduler.remove(scheduledTask)` in the code below:

```
var Scheduler = function()
{
    this.sheduledTasks = [];
}
Scheduler.prototype.add = function(scheduledTask)
{
    // adds scheduled task, maintaining their order by time. for sake of argument, it could be as simple as this:
    this.scheduledTasks.push(scheduledTask);
    this.scheduledTasks.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.time - b.time;
    });        
}
Scheduler.prototype.getNext = function()
{
    // returns the scheduledTask with lowest time value
    return this.scheduledTasks[0];
}
Scheduler.prototype.remove = function(scheduledTask)
{
    // usually called after this.getNext() to remove a handled Task,
    // but is not necessarily used to remove a ScheduledTask with the 
    // lowest time value
}


/**
 * ScheduledTask
 * @param {number} time 
 * @param {Task} task
 */
var ScheduledTask = function(time, task){
    this.time = time;
    this.task = task;
}

var Task = function(/*...*/){
   // ...
}
```

How might it be implemented, if `scheduler.remove(scheduledTask)` is to remove:

1. Instances of a particular ScheduledTask
2. All instances of ScheduledTask that have a particular Task instance at a particular time

First problem: for 1 and 2 above, it would have to maintain a map of object identity to array index, so the index can be looked up, given the object's identity.

Second problem: for 2 above, it would need to look up an index given time. But since time would be a floating point, errors could creep in meaning the precise value required for lookup would result in the wrong (or no) entry being found.

How could the above be handled?

To solve the first problem, each new object could be assigned an ID, which could be used to look them up. Is there a way that javascript does this natively, or would this have to be implemented myself?

But how to solve the second problem?

Comment: Why do you need a map? Can't the index of the object in the array be the id?

Comment: @4castle I thought the index could be integers from 0 to n-1, where 0 is the soonest task. It simplifies the `getNext()` method, but I'm open to any idea. If the index is the object ID, then I'd still need another way of finding the soonest scheduledTask, which I'd implement that way anyway?

Comment: I'd do it using a heap (min-heap) data structure comparing the timestaps.